# Debugging Javascript (and Facebook Login)

Tags: javascript, debugging, facebook

I am not good with JS :) I am messing around with adding the Facebook Login to my site here at http://www.comehike.com and on top right you can see that the FB login button renders, but if you click it, it doesn't work.

I tried putting the button into the body of the page and it actually worked.  So my sense is that its some JS issue that caused the problem.  How do I debug it in Firebug or another tool?  I am just not fluent maneuvering in these technologies.

Any help would be appreciated.  All I really want to do is make the FB login button click-able in the header :)

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Yeah I am trying to use it, but its kind of hard to start using...maybe its just me...very cluttered and I don't know what to look for lol

Comment: So what fixed it? The `window.onload` business?

Comment: @Matt Ball - well, I still have the Uncaught ReferenceError: FB is not defined error to deal with so not all my problems are solved.

Comment: If you are using Chrome, here is a nice description of built-in debugger: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts-breakpoints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a console ([Firebug](http://getfirebug.com), for instance) and the problem is pretty clear.

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: FB is not defined             www.comehike.com:94
 FB.login() called before calling FB.init().            all.js:3
```

My guess is that you're trying to call `FB.init()` before the Facebook script actually loads.

---

Line 94 contains this code:

```
window.onload=FB.init();cycleBan();
```

If you're trying to execute `FB.init()` (and also `cycleBan()`?) on the `window`'s `onload` event, that's not going to work. What the above code does is set the value *returned* by `FB.init()` to the `window.onload` handler, and then calls `cycleBan()`. Try this instead:

```
window.onload = function () {
    FB.init();
    cycleBan();
};
```

---

***Edit*** after reading a bit of the [Facebook API docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web#login), it looks like you're not passing an `appId` to `FB.init()`, which I think is necessary:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
    FB.init({ 
        appId:'YOUR_APP_ID', cookie:true, 
        status:true, xfbml:true 
    });
</script>
<fb:login-button>Login with Facebook</fb:login-button>
```

So you should change your code to  use the same structure.

---

***Edit 2*** okay, so I've never used the Facebook API before - just took another look at your page and it looks like you're already using the right basic template, and I guess you're passing the `appId` as a URL parameter. Oh well, shows how much I know.

Comment: I made that change, but the same problem still exists :( any idea what it could be still?  Thanks!

Comment: Btw, where in Firebug did you see this: Uncaught ReferenceError: FB is not defined FB.login() called before calling FB.init().  ---- I can't find the spot to get this error.  Thanks.

Comment: @Mark ....I think its just common practice to take out the actual app id from the code when asking questions in forums.  My app id is the real app id when its in the code :)

Comment: @Genadinik: I use Chrome, so it appeared in the built-in Developer Tools console (as T.J. mentioned in his answer). The second line of the error - `FB.login() called before FB.init()` only shows up in the console after you click your Login button.

Comment: Ah yes, that helped.  Now I see that it says FB is not defined.  Thank you :) ...now on to defining it somehow lol...

Comment: @Genadinik: `FB` is defined by the Facebook script that you load from `http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js`.

Answer (score 1):

On Firefox you can use the Firebug add-on (I'm guessing you know about it as you used the name in your question). Just go to the page, click the Firebug icon in the status bar at the bottom, and use the Scripts tab to go to your script code, set breakpoints, and single-step through.

You can also do this with the dev tools built into Chrome, Safari, Opera, and even IE from IE8 onward. (In earlier versions of IE you can use the free edition of VS.Net for debugging.)

One nice thing about all of these is that you can right-click an element (like your button) and choose "Inspect element" to go straight to information about it. On Chrome at least (and probably others) that includes event handlers assigned to it, which makes it easy to find things.

Comment: The right-click element is a nice little trick thanks :) but I am still not seeing any of the problems in Firebug...but the page isn't working lol

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the script connecting to the js is secure

http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js

should be

https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js

Answer (score 0):

If you pass the non existing FB app key to init() then only you get the error of 'FB.login() called before calling FB.init()'

Make sure, you haven't been doing the same.